# Rally custom grid unable to join tables

Tags: rally

I am unable to join two or three tables with the custom grid app. Is there any other way to acheive the same?

Answer (score 1):

More details would clarify what problem you are trying to solve, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091327/how-can-i-make-a-rally-app-that-reports-on-tasks-and-user-capacity-of-owners/19809975#19809975) has an example of a custom app that builds a grid based on data from two different stores.

One store uses a Task object, the other uses UserIterationCapacity object. Since currently it is not possible to create a [Rally.data.WsapiDataStore](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/api/Rally.data.WsapiDataStore) with more than one model, two WsapiDataStore objects are created in that example. Eventually a custom store [Rally.data.custom.Store](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/api/Rally.data.custom.Store) is created that accesses the fields pulled from the two models, and a grid is built based on the custom store.

Comment: Thanks. So, we won't be able to join two objects with custom grid and looks like it can be achieved via custom app. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome. You're correct, that cannot be done with a custom grid, but can be done in a custom app.